# ActiveDirectoryAuthenticationException cannot be found in Active Directory Authentication Library 2.6.1-alpha

Tags: c#, exception, azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory

When I'm trying to use `ActiveDirectoryAuthenticationException` in **Active Directory Authentication Library 2.6.1-alpha**, it can't be found. (It is there in 1.0.3 however).

What can I use instead to detect failed authentication?

**1.0.3 code:**

```
try
{
    result = authContext.AcquireToken(todoListResourceId, clientId, redirectUri, PromptBehavior.Never);

    // A valid token is in the cache - get the To Do list.
    SignInButton.Content = "Clear Cache";
    GetTodoList();
}
catch (ActiveDirectoryAuthenticationException ex)
{
    if (ex.ErrorCode == "user_interaction_required")
    {
        // There are no tokens in the cache.  Proceed without calling the To Do list service.
    }
    else
    {
        // An unexpected error occurred.
        string message = ex.Message;
        if (ex.InnerException != null)
        {
            message += "Inner Exception : " + ex.InnerException.Message;
        }
        MessageBox.Show(message);
    }
    return;
}
```

**2.6.1-alpha code:**

```
try
{
    result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(todoListResourceId, clientId, redirectUri, PromptBehavior.Auto);

    // A valid token is in the cache - get the To Do list.
    return true;
}
catch (ActiveDirectoryAuthenticationException ex) // What to use here?
{
    if (ex.ErrorCode == "user_interaction_required")
    {
        // There are no tokens in the cache.  Proceed without calling the To Do list service.
    }
    else
    {
        // An unexpected error occurred.
        string message = ex.Message;
        if (ex.InnerException != null)
        {
            message += "Inner Exception : " + ex.InnerException.Message;
        }
        MessageBox.Show(message);
    }
}

return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the library in a Windows Store app? That version of the library (i.e. ADAL WinRT) does not expose ActiveDirectoryAuthenticationException as public type, because ADAL WinRT never throws exception. It returns error in AuthenticationResult.

If you use ADAL 2.6.1-alpha in a .NET application, you can find the exception type.